# Expose Live Chat Transcript object to force.com site guest user

Tags: community, liveagent, service-cloud-console, servicecloud

Hi I want to update LIve chat transcript object at post chat page . About as of now I don't no how to  give access Live Chat Transcript object to site user so facing authorization error.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do this because to access that object you need to have a Live Agent license assigned to the user, and you can't assign Live Agent licenses to guest users. The only way I see of doing this is by creating a trigger that clones the record into a custom object and expose that custom object instead.